# Using variable in puppet exec command?

Tags: mongodb, exec, puppet

Hello Iam new to puppet and now trying to explore with puppet manifests. Actually Iam creating a manifest for mongodb and I want to use a variable inside the exec. But each time it is giving me error. My mongodb.pp is as below

```
    class db::mongodb ($interface) {
    $ip = inline_template("<%= scope.lookupvar('::ipaddress_${interface}') -%>") 
exec {'/bin/bash -c "mongo --host $ip --eval \'  db = db.getSiblingDB("test"); db.addUser({user: "test", pwd: "test", roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]})\'"' :
}
}
```

But while running this Iam getting error like below

```
could not connect to the server --eval:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
```

IP part is missing in the error because $ip is not substituting IP in the mongo command.. I tried different ways but all gives the same error. Actually I want to know how to use variable in the exec command as above in the puppet?? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are only interpolated in double-quoted strings (`""`), not single-quoted strings (`''`) and should be in the form `${ip}` when inside a string ([documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_data_string.html#interpolation), via [visual index](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_visual_index.html)).

You also have quite a few quotes there, so removing the `bash -c` wrapper would simplify it by removing one set:

```
exec { "mongo --host ${ip} --eval '  db = db.getSiblingDB(\"test\"); db.addUser({user: \"test\", pwd: \"test\", roles: [ \"readWrite\", \"dbAdmin\" ]})'" :
}
```

If the bash shell is necessary, use `provider => shell` instead.

Comment: Thanks.. giving 'provider => shell' solves the issue .. But why bin/bash with same command as above is not working??